# jqmodal and passing data to it?

Tags: jqmodal

I need to pass an id to my jqmodal popup but I'm not sure the best way to do this.

On my trigger I have a data-id set so it is like this:

```
data-id="projects"
```

and then my code which calls the popup

```
$('.jqmWindow').jqm({
   ajax:projects,
   onShow:myFadeIn,
   onHide:myFadeOut
});
```

My popup works fine, I just wonder how I can attach my id to pass it to the popup?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of detail missing from your questions, but I'm assuming that you have a trigger (let's say an  tag with data-id="projects" which should trigger your jqModal?

Take a look at [jQuery Selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Probably something like this.

```
<a href="#" data-id="projects">Click </a>

<script>

$(function () {
  $('a[data-id="projects"]').click(function () {
   $('.jqmWindow').jqm({
       ajax:projects,
       onShow:myFadeIn,
       onHide:myFadeOut
    }); 
  })
});

</script>
```